# jQuery contains multiple strings optimization

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, contains

I am writing a Greasemonkey script for hundreds similar pages.

And want to do something if AA or AB or AC...etc in $("#cont > h2")

So I tried:

```
var 1stgroup = new Array(40)
1stgroup [0] = $("#cont > h2:contains('AA')")
1stgroup [1] = $("#cont > h2:contains('AB')")
1stgroup [2] = $("#cont > h2:contains('AC')")
...
1stgroup [39] = $("#cont > h2:contains('BN')")

for (i =0; i < 40 ; i++) {
    if (1stgroup.text())       {
    //do something here
    };
};
```

And than group 2~7.

It works, but looks redundant...

How can I optimize it?

Sorry for my poor English and thanks for every reply.

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of groups? Is a `ZZ` or a `GDQ` possible? Also, what's an example of the text in `#cont > h2`?

Comment: I would start by caching the selectors. `[]` instead of `new Array()` and make sure you dont have any globals like `i`, just `var i = 0`...

Comment: AA to ZZ is only represent for some names, I use these for protect personal privacy, there are `<a  href="something">Names</a>` in `#cont > h2`

Comment: @user1503972 do you know the names ahead of time?

Comment: @hookedonwinter yes, I have already known them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- DOM traversal is the slowest part in JavaScript, so it makes sense to traverse the DOM as few times as possible.
- `:contains()` is a Sizzle extension, and is not part of CSS3, and so is not optimized by browsers. It will be slow.

With this in mind, I'd do something like this;

```
var matches = ['AA', 'AB', 'AC'];

$('#cont > h2').filter(function () {
    var text = $(this).text();

    for (var i=0;i<matches.length;i++) {
        if (text.indexOf(matches[i]) !== -1) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}).each(function () {
    // do something with each of these
});
```

Another thing you could so is sort the `matches` array and then use a search algorithm (e.g. [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)) which is smarter than linear search to detect whether the text is a match or not.

Comment: works perfectly for 5 pages, I'll work for all the other pages and than report, thanks a lot

Comment: works good for 2 groups, but I found a new question: for example, there are two persons, one's name is Harry Porter, he's in group1. Other's name is Harry Porter Jr, he's in group2. Harry Porter Jr's page with group2 setting is OK, but Harry Porter's page has both group1 setting & group2 setting, how could I deal with it?